# create screenshot of youtube with javascript api?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-javascript-api

I'm using the player javascript api v3. 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

when I do player.pauseVideo(), I want to extract the current frame in a img element.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look here. I think you can't make screenshots with the API, but this will help you

[Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots/6678156#6678156)

Comment: I suppose is not working because youtube's videos are embedded in iframes, have you tried to proxy the iframe's url?